# Specifying both image size and pixel density in srcset

Tags: html, responsive-images, srcset, pixel-density

Here's my `img` tag:

```html
<img src="https://myserver.com/image?w=667&h=375 667w" 
  srcset="https://myserver.com/image?w=1366&h=1024 1366w 1x,
  https://myserver.com/image?w=1366&h=1024&dpr=2 1366w 2x,
  https://myserver.com/image?w=1366&h=1024&dpr=3 1366w 3x,
  https://myserver.com/image?w=1024&h=768 1024w 1x,
  https://myserver.com/image?w=1024&h=768&dpr=2 1024w 2x,
  https://myserver.com/image?w=1024&h=768&dpr=3 1024w 3x,
  https://myserver.com/image?w=800&h=480 800w 1x,
  https://myserver.com/image?w=800&h=480&dpr=2 800w 2x,
  https://myserver.com/image?w=800&h=480&dpr=3 800w 3x" sizes="100%">
```

I'm using imgix which returns the image in correct pixel density based upon the `dpr` query parameter. The above does not seem to work, the image is not rendered in the right size. Am I not using the correct format?

Comment: I ended up just using a `picture` tag instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't mix the `x` and `w` descriptors in your `srcset` attribute.

I don't know imgix, but I suppose `?w=800&h=480&dpr=2` returns an image with dimensions of 1600x960 pixels. Are https://myserver.com/image?w=800&h=480&dpr=2 and https://myserver.com/image?w=1600&h=960&dpr=1 the same image?

If the image is always the same (same content and same aspect ratio) on every visible size, you should define which visible/CSS sizes you need (depends on your design, for example 800, 1200 and 1600 pixels) and write this:

```
<img
  src="https://myserver.com/image?w=800&h=400"
  srcset="https://myserver.com/image?w=800&h=400 800w,
    https://myserver.com/image?w=1200&h=600 1200w,
    https://myserver.com/image?w=1600&h=800 1600w,
    https://myserver.com/image?w=2000&h=1000 2000w,
    https://myserver.com/image?w=2400&h=1200 2400w,
    https://myserver.com/image?w=2800&h=1400 2800w,
    https://myserver.com/image?w=3200&h=1600 3200w"
  sizes="100vw">
```

The `?w=2400&h=1200` image will be downloaded by the browser for several configurations:

- screen density 1 with viewport width equal to or below 2400px
- screen density 2 with viewport width equal to or below 1200px
- screen density 3 with viewport width equal to or below 800px
- etc.

Comment: Thank you. The `dpr` part of the URL denotes the pixel density; so `dpr=1` and `dpr=2` are 1x and 2x densities respectively.

Comment: So what you're saying is that the browser will not only pick the correct size, but also the correct pixel density on its own? I therefore do not have to write 1x, 2x, 3x, etc. at all?

Comment: Well here's a question: why does the `src="https://myserver.com/image?w=800&h=400"` part above get loaded every time anyways, with every single image?

Comment: In modern browsers with native `srcset-w` support, it should not. Do you have your code online somewhere I could check?

Comment: Hmm... can you please click on the URL above again after you're connected?

Comment: hmm... I'll check again and try to capture a screenshot. May I please ask you to remove the URLs from the comment if possible? Thanks again for checking.

Comment: If you can't mix `x` and `w` in `srcset`, does that imply that it's impossible to vary quality for high-DPR only? e.g. https://blog.imgix.com/2016/03/30/dpr-quality.html

Comment: @jon_wu you'll have to use `<picture>` for that, if I understand your question

Comment: @NicolasHoizey thanks for verifying. That's what I thought. I suppose I was thrown off by the generalization that `<picture>` is good for art direction, but I guess in this case we just add triple the rules for each size, one for 1x, 2x, 3x. Seems a little verbose, but the tradeoff of more HTML and a lot less image bytes on high DPR screens seems worth it. We'll have to test this out a bit.

Comment: That's right, exactly. I have planned to do such tests also.

Comment: @jon_wu this answer states that you can supply images for high DPI screens using only w. I just tried and works perfect